# Insert an element to each list in a list at given indices

Tags: python, list

I've been struggling with something for quite a long time so I thought I would ask my question here.
I have a list of lists that looks like this : list = [[2,3,4,5,2,3],[3,4,1,6,9,9]]
Inside, there is, as you can see, two lists that have the same number of elements.
I also have what i call an "index list" that looks like this : index = [0,2,4]
What I've been trying to do is essentially to put a specific number inside each list of my list of lists at each given index of my index list.

For example, in my case, my goal is to put insert a 1 in my list in each of my 2 lists at the index 0, 2 and 4 (because my index list = [0,2,4]).

To be more clear, the ouput I would like to get is this :
[[**1**,2,3,**1**,4,5,**1**,2,3],[**1**,3,4,**1**,1,6,**1**,9,9]]
Each 1 is inserted in each list of my list of lists at the index 0,2,4 of each lists.

But I've been really struggling to achieve that : I found an answer that works for a simple list but I can't make it work for a list of multiple lists.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me !  Thanks a lot !

Comment: What code did you use for simple lists and what was the difficulty when you tried to adapt it for multiple lists?

Comment: Since you found something that works for a single list, all you need to do is drop it into a function, and call that function for each of the lists in your list-of-list. Can you provide a [mre] of the problem you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
t = [[2,3,4,5,2,3],[3,4,1,6,9,9]]
indices = [0,2,4]
k = 1
offset = 0
for i in indices:
        for ele in t:
                ele.insert(i+offset,k)
        offset+=1
print(t)
```

we maintain an offset variable and increment it by 1 to accomodate for the shift in indices every time we insert

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arrays = [[2,3,4,5,2,3],[3,4,1,6,9,9]]

indexes = [0,2,4]

for i in range(len(arrays)):
    for j in range(len(indexes)):
        k = indexes[j] + j
        arrays[i] = arrays[i][:k] + [1] + arrays[i][k:]

print(arrays)
```

Comment: Do you know that this works as intended or is it a guess?

Comment: @mkrieger1: have you tried it?

Comment: No, I can't right now.

Comment: @mkrieger1: So what's the point of asking beforehand? Try it, understand how it works, and if you still have any more doubts or questions then feel free to bring them up.

Comment: I was wondering because you wrote "try this" that you're not actually sure if it works.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Yeah, I get you. That's just how I write answers which IMHO require no other explanation but a straightforward coding solution. It means that I've tried (and tested) it, and that you're welcome to do so yourself.